# Accessing a decoded JSON data structure

Tags: arrays, json, perl

I am trying to extract a specific entry from this JSON using Perl

```
{
    "sentences": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "tokens": [
                {
                    "index":                1,
                    "word":                 "盧旺達",
                    "originalText":         "盧旺達",
                    "lemma":                "盧旺達",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
                    "characterOffsetEnd":   3,
                    "pos":                  "NN",
                    "ner":                  "PERSON"
                },
                {
                    "index":                2,
                    "word":                 "援助",
                    "originalText":         "援助",
                    "lemma":                "援助",
                    "characterOffsetBegin": 3,
                    "characterOffsetEnd":   5,
                    "pos":                  "NN",
                    "ner":                  "O"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like access to `tokens` and then to `ner`, I have been trying to use this code but it doesn`t return anything

```
$json = decode_json $json_string;

my $tokens = $json->{"sentences"}->{"tokens"};

print Dumper(\$tokens);
```

Comment: `sentences` is an array. I don't know Perl but it looks like you're accessing it as if it were a plain object. So maybe try getting the first index first? Just a guess.

Comment: The `sentences` array may have multiple elements. Do you want `ner` from all the `tokens` from all the `sentences`?

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us about the error messages that you're certainly getting from this code.

Comment: I think the syntax should be `$json->{sentences}[0]{tokens}`

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.24; # why not?!
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use open qw(:std utf8);

use JSON::MaybeXS qw( decode_json );

my $json = "...";

my $x = decode_json $json;

for my $sentence ($x->{sentences}->@*) {
    for my $token ($sentence->{tokens}->@*) {
        say $token->{ner};
    }
}
```

See [Use postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/). Of course, you can just use `@{ $x->{sentences} }` and `@{ $sentence->{tokens} }` if you must have compatibility with older `perl`s.

Comment: That's a useful lesson. I don't know whether it was deliberate, but I agree that Brian's `no warnings qw(experimental::postderef)` is inappropriate in production code. If you're going to use experimental features then you damn well want a warning to remind you of the possible source of spurious errors. A "clean" build is not such a great goal.

Comment: *"`use v5.24; # why not?!`"* because you're using it specifically to enable the `postderef` (and `say`) features, which is far from obvious.

Comment: For the record, the "**why not?!**" above is meant to be a tongue-in-cheek inducement to try nice features of recent `perl`s. It is not meant as a commentary on [@brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s blog post which predates `5.24`. It is a useful and succinct introduction suitable to the OP's level (and more helpful to the Perl beginner than official documentation on the feature).

Comment: I didn't take it to be a critique in any way, and my *"I agree"* was inappropriate. In hindsight I would write *"...but I applaud the lack of the corresponding `no warnings qw/ experimental::postderef /` that Brian uses"*. It is those who used a `no warnings` who are squirming now that v5.28 is discontinuing `experimental::smartmatch`. On a parallel idea, I would be careful about writing code that is clearly functionally complete, including even a shebang line, that you would prefer not to see in production code. Like it or not you are an authority that people will like to cite

Comment: I must add that trying *any* features of *any* `perl` is to be applauded. A few minutes of engaged experimentation would quickly correct very many misunderstandings of Perl's operators such as `my @parts = split /;/, @data` that appeared only today, and the knowledge would be *absorbed* instead of applied and discarded.

Answer (score 2):

JSON objects are represented with `{}`, and arrays with `[]`. You're missing a couple levels of arrays in your attempt:

```
{                                    # $json
    "sentences": [                   # $json->{sentences}
        {                            # $json->{sentences}->[0]
            "tokens": [              # $json->{sentences}->[0]->{tokens}
                {                    # $json->{sentences}->[0]->{tokens}->[0]
                    "ner": "PERSON"  # $json->{sentences}->[0]->{tokens}->[0]->{ner}
```

So instead of this:

`$json->{sentences}->{tokens}`

You want this:

`$json->{sentences}->[0]->{tokens}->[0]->{ner}`

If you want *all* values for the `ner` key and not just the value at specific subscripts of `sentences` and `tokens`, you'll need to use iteration:

```
my $obj = decode_json($json);

for my $sentence (@{$obj->{sentences}}) {
    for my $token (@{$sentence->{tokens}}) {
        print "$token->{ner}\n";
    }
}
```